# Find the min year of each row PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm super new to PowerBI and am running into finding the min year as some of the data are nulls. What I am trying to resolve is finding the earliest year between two columns (eventually 3 but lets start with two) in PowerBI. 
The columns look like this:

```
Date1                 Date2
5/20/2017 12:00:00    12/31/2017 12:00:00
                      8/13/2018 12:00:00
6/20/2018 12:00:00    
10/9/2017 12:00:00    7/13/2018 12:00:00
                      6/23/2018 12:00:00
```

As you can see the data has either dates in both columns or a date in just one column. How can I get the minimum of each year for every row in the column when there are nulls in the data?

An expected output would be something like this.

```
Date1                 Date2                  YearMin
5/20/2017 12:00:00    12/31/2017 12:00:00    2017
                      8/13/2018 12:00:00     2018
6/20/2018 12:00:00                           2018
10/9/2017 12:00:00    7/13/2018 12:00:00     2017
                      6/23/2018 12:00:00     2018
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Depending where you want to solve this, in a DAX formula (calculated column), 
you could use the following formula:

```
Calculated Column = 
var d1 = if(ISBLANK([date1]);2099;Year([date1]))   
var d2 = if(ISBLANK([date2]);2099;Year([date2]))
return
if(d1<d2;d1;d2)
```

In the variables just set a year higher then the highest date you can have in your datasource. In this case I used 2099.

[image: Formula and result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. Simple math Year A / Year B. If less than 1 then A otherwise B.

```
Min Year =
IF (
    DIVIDE ( Table1[A], Table1[B], 0 ) < 1,
    YEAR ( Table1[A] ),
    YEAR ( Table1[B] )
)
```